# window interval - checking for element on page and then appending to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, intervals, clearinterval

I am trying to wrap some code around jQuery that will continually check for an element on a page and when that element is present, append a defined variable to it. in this case i'm looking for a specific div with a unique ID and trying to append a defined iframe. here's what i have.

```
window.myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  $('#thankyou-container').append(iframehtml);
clearInterval(window.myInterval);
  }
), 50);
```

UPDATE:

Here's the code that I'm trying to insert into the #thankyou-container but have it load after the page loads. The issue I'm having is that this ad code (below) only loads on the page when I refresh my browser. It's so weird that it doesn't display right away:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
vm_load({
"displayId": "12584",
"publisherId": "33927",
"campaign": "9380",
"maxResults": "3",
"areaofstudy":
JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty')).CATEGORIES[0].text.replace('Business','1').replace('Criminal Justice & Legal','3').replace('Education','5').replace('Fine Arts & Design','2').replace('Health & Medicine','8').replace('Liberal Arts & Humanities','5').replace('Math, Science & Engineering','9').replace('Public Affairs & Social Sciences','13').replace('Religious Studies','5').replace('Technology','9').replace('Vocational Training',''),
"md": "1"
});
</script>
```

jQuery is loaded on the page, and the javascript file that references the vm_load function is loaded prior to this code.

I think I need something that wraps around the code and tells it to load after the page is finished loading. Could that be the solution?

Comment: Your interval runs once then is immediately cleared.  Only clear it if `$('#thankyou-container')` exists.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem...

```
window.myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var $container = $('#thankyou-container');
    if ($container.length) {
        clearInterval(window.myInterval);
        $container.append(iframehtml);
    }
), 50);
```

It will check that the element exists.  If it doesn't, nothing happens.  If it does then it clears the interval and does the append.

However, I'd recommend this approach instead...

```
function containerAppend() {
    var $container = $('#thankyou-container');
    if ($container.length) {
        $container.append(iframehtml);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(containerAppend, 50);
    }
}
containerAppend();
```

It's a little more convoluted, but it uses timeouts instead of intervals so that it takes into account anything that takes time.  With the original method you could find the element search taking longer than 50ms, which could cause problems.

Comment: If the element search takes 50ms, I think the OP would have bigger issues. :)

Comment: So I shouldn't have mentioned the 2nd method then?

Comment: No, the second method is valid. Normally people use the second method with Asynchronous Calls.

Comment: I personally prefer the 2nd method as I hate using intervals, most of the time.